# iframe calls Action method twice while setting src attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

I am calling action method from controller side through iframe.src attributes and it returns partial view but it calls twice what is the reason can any body help me on this

find my code here

```
 $('#testdailog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Split Fax',
        height: 'auto',
        width: '80%',
        position: ['top', 50],
        draggable: false,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            var frameSet = document.getElementById("testdailogFrame");
            frameSet.src='@Url.Action("TestPage", "Fax")';
 },
            close: function (event, ui) {
                var frameSet = document.getElementById("testdailogFrame");
                frameSet.src="about:blank";

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this issue by changing the code of iframe content change instead of src attribute

```
 $('#testdailog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Split Fax',
        height: 'auto',
        width: '80%',
        position: ['top', 50],
        draggable: false,
        show: 'blind',
        hide: 'blind',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
 $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("TestPage","Fax")',
                    type: 'GET',    
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(data){
                        var frameSet = document.getElementById("testdailogFrame");
                        var iframedoc = frameSet.document;

                        if (frameSet.contentDocument)
                            iframedoc = frameSet.contentDocument;
                        else if (frameSet.contentWindow)
                            iframedoc = frameSet.contentWindow.document;

                        if (iframedoc){
                            iframedoc.open();
                            iframedoc.writeln(data);
                            iframedoc.close();
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Error")';
                    }
                });
            },

}
});
```